# Why am I getting an empty array from MongoDB when querying using object properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having this seemingly trivial but persistent issue when trying to retrieve documents from MongoDB. I'm using Mongoose as the ODM and have trouble fetching documents matching a specific condition. I've had a look at similar issues/questions but no suggestion seems to work for me.

Below is a snippet of an example involving fetching meetup objects that match a specific location's name.

```
export default {
  Query: {
    //...
    meetupsByLocation: async (parent, { location }, { Meetup }, info) => {
      try {
        const meetups = await Meetup.find({ 
          "location.name": { "$eq" : location, "$exists" : true } 
        });

        // Tried this one too but to no avail
        //const meetups = await Meetup.find({ "location.name": location });

        return meetups.map(meetup => {
          meetup._id = meetup._id.toString();
          return meetup;
        });
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
    }
    //...
  },

  Mutations: {
    //...
  },
};
```

**Meetup GraphQL Schema**

```
export default `

scalar DateTime

type MeetupLocation {
  name: String!
  longitude: Float!
  latitude: Float!
}

type MeetupDetails {
  name: String!
  hostedBy: String!
  description: String!
  imageUrl: String!
  eventStart: DateTime!
  eventEnd: DateTime!
}

type Meetup {
  id: ID!
  addedBy: String!
  type: [String!]!
  location: MeetupLocation!
  details: MeetupDetails!
  photos: [String]!
  attendees: [String]!
  comments: [String]!
}

# Queries

type Query {
  meetupsByLocation(location: String!): [Meetup]!
}

`
```

**Meetup Mongoose Schema**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MeetupSchema = new Schema(
  {
    addedBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    type: { type: [String] },
    location: { 
      name: { type: String },
      longitude: { type: Number },
      latitude: { type: Number },
    },
    details: { 
      name: { type: String },
      hostedBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      description: { type: String },
      imageUrl: { type: String },
      eventStart: { type: Date },
      eventEnd: { type: Date },
    },
    photos: { type: [String] },
    attendees: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

export default mongoose.model('Meetup', MeetupSchema);
```

**NB:** Edited to include schema.

Comment: can you post your schema code

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Done.

Comment: I need you mongoose schema... You have posted graphql schema...

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Oh, my bad! There you are.

Comment: Just a bunch of ideas:
a) run `db.setLogLevel(1)` to see which query actually hits your database
b) update to the latest version of all components (especially mongoose)
c) reduce to the max: run each part of your code in isolation and see what's going on (remove any filter as a starting point, then remove the `map`, then remove the `async` bit)
d) make sure you are running your queries against the right database

Comment: Maybe stating the obvious but did you [connect](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) mongoose to your mongo database?

Comment: @dnickless Thanks for the suggestions. I found the problem. Silly me! The location stored included not just the city but both the state/province and the country. For instance, Vancouver, BC, Canada is what was stored rather than simply Vancouver. When querying, I was sending only the city i.e. Vancouver as opposed to the complete location data.

Comment: Classic. Glad you found it.